# how to use code from github with visual studio?

Tags: github

I need the following code https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp
I downloaded the zip file, now I want to include tgbot.h.
I tried to paste the tgbot folder (/include/tgbot) in the project folder but to no use.

Any solutions?

Comment: This question is not related to GitHub, but about how to setup and use a C++ library. The project provides instructions for this [here](https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp#library-installation).

Comment: the instructions are not clear to me: the code under library installation is for linux, right? How do I do it on windows?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not related to GitHub. You can open the project folder with Visual Studio. I think no need to paste tgbot folder. 
[check the solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So840.png)

If you want to open separetly include/tbbot folder then just right click on the folder and select open with visual studio.

Comment: if i simply add the folder then it won't compile a cpp file as I did not open a project